# What does 'A small medium at large' phrase means?

Tags: expressions

Just received this joke:

---

Q: What do you call a midget fortuneteller on the run from the law?

A: A small medium at large.

---

the 'Q' I understood. It's a runaway psychic gnome.

But what does `A` means? Is it geometric term or something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about explaining a joke, which the community has judged to be off-topic.

Comment: What is a geometric term?

Comment: @Mitch, the help says that _Jokes that do not rely on the English language_ are off-topic, but this joke relies on the double meanings of _medium_ and _large_, which appears to me on-topic.

Comment: @Kris I thought the `A` is about some small circle, which is smaller then medium one and so on. =)

Comment: No, the 'A' is the usual indefinite article there.

Comment: @rhetorician: I get why smiling witch as the alternate interpretation, but it should at least have something funny about that too. So, I don't get it.

Comment: I think the OP is confused about what “Q:” and “A:” mean in this context, and doesn't realize that “A(nswer):” is the punchline to the joke asked in “Q(uestion):”.

Comment: I don't know why it would be considered off-topic here, but I imagine it's on-topic at [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Bradd Szonye Although English is not my native, but in `Q` I've managed to imagine escaping psychic gnome, but `A` was considered as some geometry or something like this =) That's my stupidity, I suppose.

Comment: Q&A indicates a question and its answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Small](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/small)* in the punchline means exactly what you would expect...

> Being below the average in size or magnitude.

*[Medium](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/medium)* is another word for a psychic...

> pl. mediums A person thought to have the power to communicate with the spirits of the dead or with agents of another world or dimension.
>   Also called psychic.

and *[at large](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/at+large)* is...

> Not in confinement or captivity; at liberty: a convict still at large.

The joke relies on the double meanings of *medium* and *at large*.

Comment: Thank you. But you just described the first meaning, that is abvious. I guess, second meaning is just thee words about dimentions. Is that right?

Comment: @EL, yes, the second meaning is the normal meaning.

Comment: Thanx. I think I understood this joke. I thought it should be funnier =)

Comment: Also, the humor is partly because of hearing small', 'medium', and 'large' in sequence for something other than drink sizes.

Comment: I think one should avoid answering questions that are patently GR/ OT or otherwise disqualified.

Comment: @Kris, this looks a perfectly reasonable question to me: _Jokes that do not rely on the English language_ are off topic, but this is one that does.

Answer (score 1):

What Brian Hooper said, above; plus, the "small," "medium," and "large" are common sizes of soft drinks and other food items which are for sale at most fast-food restaurants.

> "I'll have a small fries, a medium coke, and a large milkshake, please."

Changing the *and* in "small, medium, and large" to "small medium *at* large" is therefore a play on words. A medium, in the context of this play on words, is also known as a psychic, and vice versa. A medium acts, supposedly, as a go-between who channels spirits from the beyond to the here and now.

Instead of getting a picture in your head of three different sizes of soft drinks, the picture you might get is of a small psychic/medium trying to avoid capture by the cops.  It's a mildly amusing picture, IMO.

Comment: Except that there is never a 'small' drink, or 'small' coffee available. They always start at medium, or what the Americans call 'regular'. Before 'regular' became adopted as meaning a smaller portion of something e.g. chips, drink etc. the word was mostly used for describing people's toilet pattern. One breakfast cereal was sold with the line 'keeps you regular'! I always think of this when my grandson wants a hamburger, and I'm asked if the chips are to be 'regular' or 'large'. (I never eat the trash myself)

Comment: @WS2: Starbucks at least has a secret cup size for its coffee-flavoured hot-milk drinks. So asking for a "small" latte/cappuccino/etc. means you will be given a "tall" cup, but asking for a "short" will give you a smaller cup at a marginally lower price than is on the board.

Comment: @WS2 Thanks. I'll remember that next time :)

Comment: but if I want exactly a `small` drink, then what?

Comment: @E L Ask for an espresso with some additional hot water to dilute. Or better still, go to a place where they sell decent coffee. In Britain, never a coffee-drinking nation, you can get a lovely cup of tea. But the coffee is awful, Starbucks worst of all. If you want a good cup of coffee go to France or Italy. Any mum & dad cafe will produce something incomparably better and at half the price of the miserable coffee chains.

Comment: The removal of the "small" size seems to be a predominantly USA phenomenon. Elsewhere, the "small" size is readily available (and the price of the "small" portion is shown with an "upgrade" to medium/large available), and "supersize" simply doesn't exist.
It makes the joke work much better, as "a regular large at supersize" as you'd have in the USA just doesn't work!